# how to change the properties of the blue icon of the user locations dot in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm trying to change the properties of the blue icon on a map view, is it possible to change the opacity of the blue icon or change the layer that the blue icon is in because I'm trying to put a picture onto a map view and make the picture the map and show your user location on the map. i have already tried drawing the picture with an overlay but i did not get that to work

picture of the blue dot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvuWw.png
my recent questions if you can answer please do it is about this subject

[How do i rotate an image inside a drawn polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997699/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-inside-a-drawn-polygon)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use [`SVPulsingAnnotationView`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPulsingAnnotationView), which is an open-source reimplementation of the current location dot.  You can then tweak that view before returning it in `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`.

Comment: ™jszumski im a beginner coder and have only had 1 semester of a high school class of it, i can see what can be tweaked but it doesn't look like anything i was asking for and what do you mean by returning it in the mapView:viewForAnnotation:

Comment: Any `UIView` can have its `alpha` tweaked, and using the custom pulsing view gives you the instance to tweak.  `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` is the method that allows you to return a view for a given annotation and Map Kit will then draw that view on top of the map.  You should probably read through the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) before you go any further.